# django-oauth-plus tutorial error: No module named views

Tags: django, oauth

I've been following the tutorial in the [django-oauth-plus wiki](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-oauth-plus/wiki/Home), things were going well until I hit the Requesting User Authorization section.

Well, things were going ALMOST well -- all the Client .get(...) calls had to be parametrized with **follow=True** for some reason. This worked, until this line:

```
response = c.get("/oauth/authorize/", parameters)
```

Without the follow=True, the response is a 301 (not a 200 as expected), with folllow, it pukes the following error:

```
>>> response = c.get("/oauth/authorize/", parameters, follow=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 447, in get
response = self._handle_redirects(response, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 567, in _handle_redirects
response = self.get(path, QueryDict(query), follow=False, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 445, in get
response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 229, in get
return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_oauth_plus-2.0-py2.6.egg/oauth_provider/views.py", line 94, in user_authorization
authorize_view = get_callable(authorize_view_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 124, in wrapper
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 91, in get_callable
lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named views
```

My Python/Django-fu isn't that strong, I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure this out. Any ideas?

Thanks!